# Could someone assist with the following IBM Watson Assistant error: Lite org is not allowed to provision non-lite plans

Tags: db2, command-line-interface, watson-assistant, ibm-cloud-functions, watson-assistant-solutions

I have a chat bot which i created using the Watson Assistant interface. I would like to connect my chat bot to a database. I did some research and found that I can connect my bot to a database by using cloud functions

(I am following the steps to connect my bot to the db using the following tutorial : https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson&cm_mc_uid=95784327520315578879847&cm_mc_sid_50200000=37695501561065026622&cm_mc_sid_52640000=87569701561065937701).

That being said, Im Utilizing Powershell and passing the following command in it,`" ibmcloud service create dashDB Entry eventDB"`. When passed , I get the following error

> "Server error, status code: 502, error code: 10001, message: Service
>   broker error: Lite org is not allowed to provision non-lite plans".

Note, I was using the Lite plan but when I received this error, I updated the plan to a trial Plus plan for 30 days and the issue still persists.

Could someone please advise.

- -Updated the account to from Lite to Plus plan.
- -Changing my region within cli

I do not know the expected outcome but I know what I want to do next. The next command I want to pass is: `'ibmcloud service key-create eventDB slackbotkey'`

Comment: Still a problem?

Comment: @data_henrik Hi, Yes , its still a problem. Im trying another solution where I use the Python api instead but I would still like a solution to this problem. Could you assist?

Comment: Could you try to create the service using the browser UI? https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/db2-warehouse

Comment: Thank you! I see where I made the error. I created an instance in the gui called Db2-8f mistakenly thinking of it to be db2-warehouse